# VSS command-line merge doesn't launch diff tool

Tags: visual-sourcesafe

I've set VSS client up to use kdiff3 for 3-way merging, which is really useful. But when I use the command-line tool SS.exe, it is just making changes in the file. I'm merging trunk changes into my working branch, and VSS either replaces my branch changes with the trunk version, or marks every change in the branch as a conflict.

VSS won't let me merge into a branch in the IDE so this is my only option, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

We gave up on using SS.exe manually, and just did the following:

In VS (2012) Go to tools and options.
Select Source Control in the left pane->configure User Tools (button) -> Add
Setup your comparison tool with the following data:

```
Extension: .* 
Operation: Compare 
Command: <location>\kdiff3.exe 
Arguments: %1 --fname %6 %2 --fname %7
```

Setup your merging tool with the following data:

```
Extension: .* 
Operation: Merge 
Command: <location>\kdiff3.exe 
Arguments: %3 --fname %8 %2 --fname %7 %1 --fname %6 -o %4
```

Now merges will work from IDE like a charm.